# Check whether virtual keyboard will be shown (or is hardware keyboard present?)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

In my application (WinRT App, C#) I need to know if the virtual keyboard will be shown if I set the focus on a TextBox (`TextBox.Focus()`). The idea is to automatically set the focus if the virtual keyboard will not be shown (otherwise it will be too distracting - the user has to manually focus the TextBox if he wants to edit the text on a tablet).

`new KeyboardCapabilities().KeyboardPresent > 0` is not working as it is always true (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/5be268ba-b662-4a0e-ac82-ac1e90c31b56/).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, you know it isn't going to work.  So there's little point in trying to make it work.  Just assume a pad.

Comment: Nice, what a limited API... and yet Microsoft encourages to support all device types...

Comment: Well, you already know the problem is caused by Bluetooth.  Bitching about that to Microsoft isn't going to do you much good, send your grievances to the industry group.  Although I reckon, given the amount of luck I've had with Bth, you'll be joining a mile long line of programmers carrying blunt instruments.

Comment: The system knows whether to show the virtual keyboard or not, I don't see why the developer can't access this information...